# Keep receiving "Else: endif not found." error

Tags: linux, csh

This is the prompt for my script:
Script that asks the user “Are you OK?”

If user replies y or Y, then say “glad to hear it” else if the user enters n or N then print  “sorry that you are not feeling good”. If the user enters some other character, then print in-correct choice and ask the question again.

Here's what I have:

```
#! /bin/csh
echo "Are you OK? "
set n = $<
set loop = 1
if (("$n" == "y") || ("$n" == "Y")) then
    echo "glad to hear it"
else if (("$n" == "n") || ("$n" == "N")) then
    echo "sorry that you are not feeling good"
else
    echo "in-correct choice"
    while ( $loop == 1 )
      echo "Are you OK? "
      set n = $<
      if (("$n" == "y") || ("$n" == "Y")) then
        echo "glad to hear it"
        set loop = 0
      else if (("$n" == "n") || ("$n" == "N")) then
        echo "sorry that you are not feeling good"
        set loop = 0
      else
        echo "in-correct choice"
      endif
    end
endif
```

I keep receiving the error "else: endif not found." Also the echo line "glad to hear it" runs every time regardless if the user input is right or not. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Hmm. Spellcheck doesn't support `csh`. Sorry. I didn't see any obvious problems with your code, and when I copy/pasted into a new file and ran it locally, your code worked as expected. My experience with csh (15 yrs ago), lead me to think you have an extra character at the end of a line that is throwing off the add-hoc parser that is `csh`. If you're using `vi`, issue the cmd `:set list`. Note that now all tab chars are converted to `^I` and the end of each line is flagged with the `$` char. Look especially at the end of each line and if there are any extra space chars, remove them ...

Comment: .... and see if that helps. Maybe the shortcut is to copy/paste your code directly from your Q here into a new file, then `chmod +x myScript.csh` and pray the problem goes away. I've seen this sort of thing happen numerous times, where it is just a mystery, and recreating (carefully) the file made the problem go away. Good luck!

Comment: opps, make that `shellcheck` doesn't support `csh`. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

Just add new line after Your last endif statement:

```
...
    end
endif
#new line
```

Or I recommend always end csh scripts with exit status and You should be good to go:

```
...
    end
endif
exit (0)
```

Anyway here is also little rewrite of Your script:

```
#!/bin/env csh
while (1)
  echo "Are you OK?"
  set n = "$<"
  if (("$n" == "y") || ("$n" == "Y")) then
    echo "glad to hear it"
    break
  else if (("$n" == "n") || ("$n" == "N")) then
    echo "sorry that you are not feeling good"
    break
  else
    echo "in-correct choice"
  endif
end
exit (0)
```

- `set n = $<`  here is danger better `set n = "$<"` in order not to handle e.g. string `y abc` as yes